# ClientAuthenticationMethod CLIENT_SECRET_POST not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Currently I´m working on an authentication solution using spring, oauth client and webClient.

I need send clientId and clientSecret inside the body without base64.

However, CLIENT_SECRET_POST configuration keeps sending Basic authentication. Is there another way to implement client_secret_post ?

Configuration classes

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

WebClientConfiguration

```
    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.clientName.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.clientName.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.clientName.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.clientName.authorization-grant-type}") AuthorizationGrantType grantType

    )
    {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("clientName")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(grantType)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction filter = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                authorizedClientManager);

        filter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("clientName");
        return WebClient.builder().filter(filter)
                .build();
    }
```

WebClient request

```
webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(URL_PATH +"/account/"+ id).build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(AccountVO.class)
            .block();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Boot 3.1.1 release, they have changed oAuth2 implementation, here go with spring documentation for your [reference](https://spring.io/blog/2023/05/24/spring-authorization-server-is-on-spring-initializr)